# Access Account Discriminator in Anchor

Tags: anchor, program

I wish to access the discriminator of an Account Type inside a program.

The only method I found is
`let mut init_storage_data = ctx.accounts.storage.try_to_vec().unwrap();`, but it's skips the first 8 bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the [anchor_lang::Discriminator](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/trait.Discriminator.html) trait and access the discriminator with `T::DISCRIMINATOR`.